# How to create boxed text without title in Sphinx?

Tags: python-sphinx, restructuredtext

There are several directives in Sphinx to create a boxed text, ex `.. note::` or `.. topic::`, but they all include a title. Is it possible to create a boxed text without title?

Comment: A couple of ways include custom CSS `p.admonition-title {display: none;}` or a raw HTML directive.

Answer (score 7):

You can use [Generic Admonition](https://docutils.sourceforge.io/docs/ref/rst/directives.html#generic-admonition).

[image]

```
.. admonition:: \ \ 

   You can use a `Generic Admonition`_

.. hint::
   | Generic Admonition still requires a title, but an escaped whitespace can be used!
   | 
   | This can be convenient, because the box uses a style consistent with other admonitions.
   |
   | And might spare you from having to fiddle with CSS while Rome burns :)

.. _Generic Admonition: https://docutils.sourceforge.io/docs/ref/rst/directives.html#generic-admonition
```

Comment: Thanks, but this is still not what I want. I already refused using rst for writing documentation in favor of markdown + raw html.